# Is there any way to smash things for wood in the Long Dark?

Tags: the-long-dark

Trying the Long Dark out; loving it so far for atmosphere, but it's driving me mental that I seem to be in a place with nothing but woodstoves in structures all over the place, and no way to smash chairs or anything else for fuel. Is there any way to gather fuel other than hoping I get lucky and find "reclaimed wood"? You'd think in a stark desperate battle for survival in the Canadian wilderness I might be willing to sacrifice a wooden bunkbed or two.

Comment: In a new update you actually smash stuff now, just wanted to mention that the current answer is outdated ;)

Comment: @Timtech: Reply to the answer instead. Other answers may be posted, rendering your comment obsolete.

Answer (score 5):

Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to open the survival panel. One of the options is "Forage Wood":

[image]

If you're outdoors, you get three options: Tinder, Softwood (i.e. Cedar firewood) or Hardwood (i.e. Fir firewood).

[image]

If you're indoors, you get two options: Tinder or Reclaimed wood.

[image]

You don't appear to need any tools to forage for wood, and I haven't noticed any furniture disappearing when I do it indoors.

Comment: After 7 years, its fascinating to see how much the game has progressed, thanks for the screenshots

Answer (score 5):

In the current version (December 2017), if you have a hatchet,  you can break up crates, planks, pallets, tables, chairs for "reclaimed wood" which is usable for fires or for constructing snares.

Outside you can use a hatchet to break up fir and cedar branches for firewood.

I think you can also use a heavy hammer to break up lumber indoors.

Comment: This answer is still current as of June 2021.